# Difference Between (x && y || z) and (x AND y OR z)

Tags: php, comparison, operators

I was wondering if there are any disadvantages of using words (e.g. `AND`, `OR`) instead of their code equivalents (`&&`, `||`) for comparison? Besides the later being a compatible syntax with many other programming languages, is there any other reason for choosing them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AND is not the same like &&

for example:

```
<?php $a && $b || $c; ?>
```

is not the same like

```
<?php $a AND $b || $c; ?>
```

the first thing is
(a and b) or c

the second
a and (b or c)

because || has got a higher priority than and, but less than &&

For more information check out [PHP Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and [Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: I might be arguing semantics now, but imo they ARE the same (functionality wise). They do differ in precedence though.

Answer (score 5):

An unanticipated disadvantage comes when used with the `=` operator.

```
$result = false || true; # true, $result is true
/* Translated to result = (false || true) */
```

and

```
$result = false or true; # true, $result is false
/* Translated to (result = false) or true */
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHP manual (in [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)) talks about what you ask in your question:

> The reason for the two different variations of "and" and "or" operators is that they operate at different precedences. (See [Operator Precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).)

So the difference is in the precedence, not the logical meaning of each single operator.

In your example: `(x && y || z)` and `(x AND y OR z)` you won't see any difference between the two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

They do the same thing, but the `&&` and `||` operators have higher precedence than `AND` and `OR`.

Basically I think this can become confusing so if you just stick to one notation and not mix them, you'll be fine and your code will remain readable.